# Show that there is a number $x\in[\pi/2, \pi]$ such that $\tan(x) = -x$

Tags: calculus, functions

Can I solve this by the intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I solve this by the intermediate value theorem?

Yes, you can. Consider $f(x) = \tan x + x$. Notice that $f(\pi/2 + \epsilon) \approx -\infty$ for small $\epsilon$ (more formally, the right limit as $x \to \pi / 2$ of $f(x)$ is $-\infty$) while $f(\pi) = \pi$. Now the intermediate value theorem gives you want you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is equivalent to proving that
$$ f(z)=z \cot z = z^2+\frac{\pi z}{2}=g(z)\tag{1} $$
for some $z\in I=\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. That is trivial since $f(z)$ decreases from $1$ to $0$ on $I$ while $g(z)$ increases from $0$ to $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$ on $I$, and both $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are continuous over $I$. By approximating $z\cot z$ with $1-\frac{z^2}{3}$ we also get:
$$ z\approx \frac{-3\pi+\sqrt{192+9\pi^2}}{16} $$
hence the solution to the original problem is about:
$$ x\approx \frac{5\pi+\sqrt{192+9\pi^2}}{16}.\tag{2} $$